How many NPT threads of engagement are recommended to hold a vacuum?
Question:
Is there a rule of thumb for how many NPT threads are necessary to hold a vacuum? Or, better, is there a chart which shows how many threads are necessary for a given depth of vacuum?
Backstory:
Note: This question is a general one about NPT sealing. I'm curious, and I'd like to learn more about this. However, I'll give the backstory in case it's useful context. (But solving the backstory problem doesn't answer the NPT question...)
I have a Fisher Scientific vacuum oven, and I would like to upgrade the piping so that I can pull a faster vacuum. The upgraded oven should be just as capable of holding a vacuum as the original.
The existing fitting leaving the chamber is a 1/4" NPT, which means 18 threads per inch (tpi). If I upgrade to a 3/8" NPT, then I keep the same number of threads. Presumably, then, this will seal equally well.
However, if I upgrade to a 1/2" NPT, then I go from 18tpi to 14tpi. Since the stainless steel oven wall is of a given thickness, I cannot thicken the joint to have more threads of engagement. So I will simply have ~25% fewer threads. The design question then becomes if we will be satisfied with the reduced sealing performance.

what about adding a nut?

Why do you believe that your NPT joint is the weakest point in the leak rate? What relative increase in pump rate are you wanting, eg 10% or 110%. What is the pump rate limit on your tubing to the oven to even believe that you can improve the pump rate at the oven by making tighter seal at the chosen joint?

@JeffreyJWeimer I don't believe it is the weak point. I suspect the current weak point is the silicone gasket. However, upgrading my vacuum oven isnot really what the question is, my question is, "Is there a rule of thumb for how many threads...?" Certainly, the seal would be terrible with only one thread of engagement, and conversely with >6 it would be about as good as an NPT seal can get.

@SolarMike see response to Jeff. I'm interested in learning about NPT and sealing. My specific problem is only given for the backstory to the question.

just to be sure: your question now is to have the seal hold at least the same if not a lower base pressure, which is different from asking to allow a faster pump rate

@JeffreyJWeimer my question is whether there is a guide/chart/rule-of-thumb for the quality of an NPT seal vs. threads of engagement. You are correct, I am not asking about how to achieve a faster pump rate.

Typical design, for any of the types and classes of NPT, whether straight or tapered, and regardless on material, is to have about a square joint. You want thread engagement to equal nominal diameter. If nothing else, it lets you design a pipe layout where the pipe fitter isn't cursing the day you were born.

The concern should be more about gas bypass through the grommet and fitting around the tube than about gas bypass through the number of threads on the fitting that holds everything together. By doubling the radius of the fitting, you double the circumference area that can allow gas to leak in to the chamber. Conversely, by doubling the radius of the tube inlet, you increase the conductance in the tube perhaps by a factor of $2^3 = 8$ in molecular flow (high vacuum) conditions.
When you insist on continuing down the path to estimate flow through the threads, consider that volumetric conductance (m$^3$/s) in molecular flow is given approximately as
$$C \approx \frac{r^3}{l}$$
with $r$ as the pore radius and $l$ as the path length. Assume that gas diffuses along the thread lines, not over them. Calculate the path length change along a spiral thread line in going from Thread A to Thread B to Thread C. The inverse ratio of path lengths is the change in conductance flow rate. Doubling the path length along the thread line will cut the conductance along the threads for that fitting in half. Tighter fittings are equivalent to smaller pore radius (the width for gas to flow along the thread line).
Finally, the governing equation in any system (tube, chamber, fitting, ...) depends on pump speed $S$ (m$^3$/s), conductance $C$, and pressure as
$$p S = C(p_x - p)$$
where $p_x$ is the external pressure (presumably atmospheric) and $p$ is the operating base pressure of the pump and system.
For further information, search on-line search for leak rate and pump speed.
In summary: Does information exist in the public domain to correlate vacuum leak rate or base vacuum pressure to NPT thread count ... Likely not, because the threads are not where vacuum leaks occur for such fittings. Rather than continue here, you will do better to contact a vacuum component vendor and seek a specialist to confirm.

Thanks, that was super informative!

@KennSebesta A common respect is to mark an answer as complete when it completes the understanding that you need.

Absolutely. I don't (yet) believe your answer is the answer to the asked question, even though it is interesting and informative. I need time to think it through.

See the update.
